# Make drop down menues toggle on clicking on their labels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have several selects on my site. I am using react. When you click on the arrow, it toggles open and lets you select from the dropdown, but when you click over the label nothing happens.

This is my html structure

```
<select id="people" name="people">
    <option disabled=""></option>
    <option value="1">John Does</option>
    <option value="2">Barry Jones</option>
    <option value="3">Johanna Crest</option>
</select>

<label class="label-class" for="people">
    People
</label>
```

I would like to toggle each doprdown open when clicking their corresponding label, and this to happen for each of the dropdowns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using react you can bind an event to the label `onClick={your_function}`

Comment: Yes, but what would my_function look like

Comment: something like : 

toggleLabel = (e) => {
   this.setState({your_dropdow: open}) 
/* if you have your dropdown changes on the state but this way seems nasty to me, you should put your react code here so i can see how you did it so far */
}

Comment: I don't want to put my_drowpdown because then i would have to do it differently for each, it is a component , I was hoping maybe something like parent.select:open or something like that

Comment: Then you can put your dropdown and label inside a div and you put an onclick on the div and you just check the target to trigger the dropdown later